# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint '...'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Cliente'. The duplicate key value is (<NULL>)

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, constraints

When I try to insert a NULL into a column from my table, it gives me error of violation and I can't understand why. As you see, I have already put into the table one NULL type but it's from a different row, with a different ID and a different name. Please check the screenshot below:

| id | nif | nome | morada |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 213 | aaaa | gggggg |
| 2 | NULL | bbbb | xxxxxx |
| 3 | 215 | cccc | qwqwdq |

This is the query that I'm using to try to insert another row of data, similar with the **id -> 2**
column:
`INSERT INTO Cliente (id, nome)  VALUES ('5', N'Arnaldo Magalhães')`

This is the query I used to create the table on the screenshot:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cliente](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [nif] [int] NULL,
    [nome] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [morada] [varchar](50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
)
```

That's the DDL:

```
USE [Restaurante]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Cliente]    Script Date: 6/17/2022 12:14:11 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cliente](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [nif] [int] NULL,
    [nome] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [morada] [varchar](50) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [nif] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And that's the error:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Cliente__DF97D0F220E9258E'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Cliente'. The duplicate key value is (NULL).

Comment: You've created a unique index on `nif` - therefore you are only allowed `null` once - more than that is a duplicate.

Comment: @DaleK thanks for answering, how can i change it? i mean, nif in Portugal is the social security number, i need it to be unique, but i need it to accept more than one null... is that even possible?

Comment: @DaleK so, how do i change it then? to accept more than one null?

Comment: @DaleK i did man and i also saw that post before, still couldn't get it... but thank you for clarifying me!

Comment: The easy answer is `Just filter a unique index`.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=832dbef7a659ac7e3b0c1b4a0c0e19c9